# Libero soc & ide for windows 7 x32

Tags: vhdl, fpga, system-on-chip

I tried more than once to install Microsemi libero (http://www.microsemi.com/products/fpga-soc/design-resources/design-software/libero-soc) but i always get an error, is libero is just used for x64 OS? I read in the device support that it can work on x32, am I missing something?

Comment: It's difficult enough to install under Linux, I've never tried it on Windows. Give us half a clue about the error you get and someone *might* be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I gave up installing it under Linux and installed it on my old desktop computer that runs Windows XP.

According to this info:

http://www.microsemi.com/products/fpga-soc/design-resources/design-software/libero-soc#device-support

The tools has been tested on both 32 bits and 64 bits version.

I installed mine on 32 bits XP. What kind of error message are you getting?

Comment: I'm using Win7 x32 not linux, couldn't even fully download the software, it fails while downloading, sometimes it finish but shows this error: Could not luch driver installation wizard

Comment: You probably need to install the JRE before installing this SW, I already had the latest JRE installed, so I think that is why it worked on my old PC.